# trying to replace all \n inside textarea to '\n (4 spaces) ' and viceversa but only one \n is found

Tags: javascript, jquery

here's the link where I'm trying this:

http://jsbin.com/ajirim/2/edit#source

the js code:

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(dao);
    });

   function dao()            {
   var x = $('textarea').val();

   if(x.substring(0,4) == '    ')
   {
      x = x.replace('\n    ','\n').substr(4);
   }
   else
   {
      x = '    '+ x.replace('\n', '\n    ');
   }

   $('textarea').val(x);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `g` flag:

```
   if(x.substring(0,4) == '    ')
   {
      x = x.replace(/\n {4}/g,'\n').substr(4);
   }
   else
   {
      x = '    '+ x.replace(/\n/g, '\n    ');
   }
```

Comment: it works, only I did `/\n    /g`, instead of `/n\n {4}/g`, what does the {4} stands for ?

Comment: @Omu The `{n}` syntax in regular expressions means "previous character n times repeated" => four spaces are the same as `(space){4}`. Read more at http://www.regular-expressions.info/